# Twitter Fabric Integration 403 Exception

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to pull Tweets from a specific users timeline on Twitter using Fabric.

I've got the Fabric Studio plugin installed and working.

```
TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));

TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient().getStatusesService()
            .userTimeline(null, "fabric", 10, null, null, null, true, null, false,
                new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<List<Tweet>> result) {
                        for (Tweet t : result.data) {
                            android.util.Log.d("tweet", t.text);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                        android.util.Log.d("tweet exception", exception);
                    }
                });
```

The key and secret are right, based on my account and this code will actually work for a while. Then after a period of time, and after I've made a few changes (not related to the Fabric integration) it will start throwing the following exception.

exception com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: 403 Forbidden

This has happened 4-5 times and is only solved by re-creating the app from scratch. I'm not sure whether I'm hitting some cap, a time-out or some change I'm making is breaking it. Re-generating and adding the keys does not fix the issue.

Comment: i think the problem is related to you keys, to be sure contact twitter support team from you fabric account

Comment: Why do you think that? I've regenerated the keys numerous times. A Twitter DA I spoke to was useless.

Comment: i think the "403 Forbidden" is something related to Twitter not your code, i'm using the same code and its working just fine. anyway please put all you logcat

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way ..

```
    TwitterCore.getInstance().logInGuest(new Callback<AppSession>() {
         @Override
         public void success(Result<AppSession> appSessionResult) 
       {
        //Your Code goes here ...........
       }
        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) 
       {

         }
      )};
```

For More de tail [GO HERE](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/authentication.html)